# Как во внешнем отчёте вывести продажи по конкретному контрагенту в отдельный столбец?

Tags: 1с

Как во внешнем отчёте вывести продажи по конкретному контрагенту в отдельный столбец?

Answer (score 1):

Отчет внешний или нет не имеет никакого значения. Необходимо добавить группировку по контрагенту в столбец и добавить условие на необходимого Вам контрагента.